# php - return error for js promise to catch

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, promise

Is that even possible to return some kind of error (ie using header()) from php file that is received by ajax call and reveived as error (via catch method?)

consider such a php (example doesnt work correctly):

```
<?php 

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");



if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] == 0 ) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        print json_encode(["test" => 123]);
    }
else
    {
       header('HTTP/1.1 1337 Internal Server Kalreg');
       header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
}
?>
```

and js:

```
axios.get('loginStatus.php', { crossDomain: true })
        .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });


    }
  }
```

Now because $_SESSION['user_id'] is set to 1 server error is generated, and because of that catch in js should react in proper way. In fact it is not - in chrome-dev-tools i get an error:

> xhr.js?ec6c:178 OPTIONS
>   http://192.168.0.15/game/src/server/loginStatus.php 500 (Internal
>   Server Error) Failed to load
>   http://192.168.0.15/game/src/server/loginStatus.php: Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500.

Is that possible? Or should i return just JSON file with error or not and manage it with .then not .catch?

Kalreg.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want catch to be executed and this is decided on server-side, then you will need to set an unsuccessful status code via [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php). A status code of 417 (Expectation failed) seems to be a good pick in your case, but you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) what you can pick from.

Comment: This works, however i still get an error in console, although catch is executed. So i get catch executed and also console is filled with error response:  2xhr.js?ec6c:178 OPTIONS http://192.168.0.15/game/src/server/loginStatus.php 417 (Expectation Failed)
Failed to load http://192.168.0.15/game/src/server/loginStatus.php: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 417.
It is quite annoying because i get error however i do want to get this error becaue user is not logged in. Any idea to solve it?

Comment: @Kalreg if that is a problem you can call clear() inside the catch which will clear the error messages in console.